# Проблема с циклом for C++

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы

Пытаюсь отсортировать столбцы двумерного массива по возрастанию первой строки с помощью цикла путем перестановки местами столбцов. Но если смотреть результат, то цикл как будто не доходит до конца, либо вообще не сортирует. Пробовал везде менять значения (0 на 1, 1 на 0 и т.д.), но все равно не получается. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема. В массиве 2 строки и 8 столбцов.

Пример:

**1 4 2 5 0**

5 7 1 3 1

Должно получиться:

**0 1 2 4 5**

1 5 1 7 3

```
for (int i = 1; i < 1; ++i) {  
   for (int k = 1; k < 7; ++k) {  
        if (coords1[i][k] > coords1[i][k + 1]) {
            std::swap(coords1[i][k], coords1[i][k + 1]);
            std::swap(coords1[i+1][k], coords1[i+1][k + 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: 1) Внешний цикл, если не ошибаюсь, у Вас не сработает: у Вас сразу же выполнится условие выхода. ```i=1; i<1 => 1<1``` -всегда ложь. 2) Внешний цикл здесь, по-моему, вообще не нужен, по крайней мере, в таком виде. Уберите  его. 3) Нумерация элементов массива в с++ начинается с нуля. Следовательно, первый элемент массива (с индексом 0) Вы игнорируете. 4) условие внутреннего цикла ```k<7``` на приведенном Вами примере должно приводить к ошибке, тем более, что в теле цикла есть обращение к индексу ```k+1```, то есть в последнее итерации к элементу с индексом 7, а максимальный индекс в примере 4

Comment: Еще бы добавил, что лучше выбрать другую сортировку. Вы же будете каждый раз менять местами не 2 элемента, а 2 * (кол-во строк) элементов.

Comment: @HMS_TRINIDAD то есть с такой сортировкой нет смысла возиться?

Comment: Ну лучше выбрать другую. Хотя с массивом 2х8 всё не так критично, но всё же лучше запоминать индексы столбцов для свапа и в конце итерации свапать столбцы